# return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass()

Tags: objective-c, xcode, lldb

I need to fix this error exactly.

Error:

[image: capture of run]

Comment: what type of error you get, this is not enough to solve your problem. Your will be displayed on console, send that error

Comment: I put a screenshot that shows the execution, did you see it please

Comment: Click on Continue program execution button up to 3 or 4 times, an error will be shown on log console. In screen shot left side second button after blue button

Comment: Because this error will comes a lot of reasons

Comment: I clicked several times on this button but nothing has changed

Comment: Add an swift/objc exception breakpoint and try to reproduce the bug :) https://learnappmaking.com/debugging-fix-bugs-xcode-debugger-breakpoints/

Answer (score 0):

What does the backtrace show when you crash?  You can either look at the Debug Navigator in Xcode's Navigators pane, or issue the command:

(lldb) bt

When a thread crashes in Xcode, Xcode will show the source for the youngest frame that has source information.  That means if you crash in some system library, the source that gets shown doesn't really tell you what the crash was about, you have to look at the backtrace to see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put exception break point in your Xcode.

see my screen shots

[image: Select break point in your Xcode]

[image: Click + button in below Xcode, you can get list]

In this list select Exception Breakpoint.

[image: You can get this options and click on Add Action]

[image: Now you can get like this, you enter your exception here]

Ex:NSInvalidArgumentException

Enable break points in your Xcode
[image]

Now run your project again. Your Xcode will stopped at exact error point...